Is $\mathbb{Z} \ast F$ quasi-isometric to $F_2$ where $F$ is a non-trivial finite group?
In my geometric group theory notes, this was given sometime back as an exercise, saying it is true, but I don't think this is true.
To prove quasi-isometry I need to find a quasi-isometric map $\phi: F_2 = \langle x,y | - \rangle \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \ast F = G$, say. The metrics are the usual word metrics on the groups, and with the usual finite generating sets as basis. Take $\mathbb{Z} \cong \langle a | - \rangle$. $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ cannot both be mapped into $F$. Because then $d_G(a^m, Im(\phi)) \geq |m| \forall m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and hence is unbounded. Now if we suppose have $\phi(x) = a^i$ for some $i \in \mathbb{Z}$, then we have again $d_G(f_1a^mf_2, a^i) \geq |m| \forall m \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $f_1, f_2 \in F$ are any two non-identity elements. It feels like no matter to what elements I map $x$ and $y$, I can always find some elements in $G$ which are at unbounded distances from $Im(\phi)$. On the other hand, I think we can prove that it is at least a quasi-isometric embedding.

Do you know how to prove that $G$ is virtually free? Alternatively, do you know what the Bass-Serre tree of $\mathbb Z\star F$ is?

$G$ has presentation $\langle X_1, X_2 | R_1 \cup R_2 \rangle$ where $G = \langle X_1 | R_1 \rangle \ast \langle X_2 | R_2 \rangle$, which is the basic definition of free product. Because $F$ is a finite group, should it not mean that $G$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ that has finite index? Also I don't think that I should know the Bass-Serre tree if I don't know anything about $F$ other than the fact that it is finite, right?

No, a finite group cannot contain an infinite group. It seems like you do not have enough background to deal with this problem. Why are you trying to solve it?

How is $G$ a finite group??

Sorry, I misread what you wrote. No, it does not follow that $G$ contains $\mathbb Z$ as an infinite index subgroup. But you still do not have enough background. My suggestion is to read a bit on combinatorial group theory, like Lyndon and Schupp. You are not ready for the problem you are trying to solve.

Could you just say if the answer is true or false? That would be immensely helpful.

You can just define a map from $\mathbb{Z} \ast F \longrightarrow F$ and claim that the kernel is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ and this obviously has finite index. Am I clearer this time?

You can define it, but the kernel will not be $\mathbb Z$. In fact, unless $F$ is trivial, the free product $\mathbb Z * F$ is never virtually cyclic. But the answer to the question in your post is positive. However, as I said, you do not have the tools to prove it. Once you know more about combinatorial group theory or group actions on trees, the result follows easily.

The map you have defined is one possible way to go: $\mathbb{Z}\ast F\rightarrow F$ has kernel of finite index, which is free.

You have sketched of a proof that a quasi-isometry
$$\phi : \underbrace{\left<x\right> * \left<y\right>}_{F_2} \to \underbrace{\left<a\right> * F}_{\mathbb Z * F}
$$
cannot exist, where $F$ is a finite group.
I will limit my answer to a critique of your sketch (if you want to ask why $\phi$ does exist, you can follow up on the suggestions in the comments).
In your sketch you discuss a couple of cases based on a couple of ways of choosing values of $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$. But a strategy that is based on choosing values of $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ will not work. I'll explain why this is so in just the first case that you discuss.
You wrote:

$\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ cannot both be mapped into $F$. Because then $d_G(a^m, Im(\phi)) \geq |m| \forall m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and hence is unbounded

and on that basis you conclude that $\phi$ cannot exist if $\phi(x),\phi(y) \in F$.
I have to say that it's rather unclear how you deduced the inequality $d_G(a^m, Im(\phi)) \geq |m|$ for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, but I think I can guess: it looks like you are using the assumption that $\phi(x) \in F$ and $\phi(y) \in F$ to conclude that $\phi(F_2) \subset F$. But that conclusion is unwarranted.
If $\phi$ were known to be both a quasi-isometry and a group homomorphism, then from the assumption that $\phi(x) \in F$ and $\phi(y) \in F$, and from the knowledge that $F$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z * F$, it would indeed follow that $\phi(F_2) \subset F$, and then the inequality you write would indeed be correct. So this first case of your proof strategy does show that there does not exist a function $\phi : F_2 \to \mathbb Z * F$ that is both a quasi-isometry and a homomorphism, and that takes $x$ and $y$ to elements of $F$.
And I suspect that, with further hard work, your proof strategy might be extendable to a proof that for certain finite groups $F$ there does not exist any function $\phi : F_2 \to \mathbb Z * F$ that is both a quasi-isometry and a homomorphism (beware of the case $F=\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$, though... such a function does indeed exist in that case).
But that is not what the problem asks. Instead, it asks only whether a function $\phi$ exists that is a quasi-isometry.
A homomorphism is indeed completely determined by its values on a generating set, and if you knew that $\phi$ was a homomorphism then your inequality would be correct.
But if you only know that $\phi$ is a quasi-isometry, and so it need not be a homomorphism, then knowing just the values $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ tells you nothing about other values $\phi(g)$ for $g \in \left<x\right> * \left<y\right>$. In fact for any given quasi-isometry of a group, you can change the function arbitrarily on an arbitrary finite subset, and the result will still be a quasi-isometry. Even more, you can change every value of a quasi-isometry, as long as you move all of the values by a uniformly bounded distance in the metric on the codomain of $\phi$; the result will still be a quasi-isometry.
To summarize, quasi-isometries can be very different from homomorphisms. In the case I have critiqued, for a quasi-isometry $\phi$, just knowing that $\phi(x),\phi(y) \in F$ it does not follow that $Im(\phi) \subset F$. And in other cases you might want to pursue, again just knowing the values of $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ gives you no information at all about other values of $\phi$.
So your proof strategy is invalid.
